# Enable scrolling in UIViewController for Xamarin

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, xamarin, scrollview

I have a UIViewController created via Storyboard in Xamarin Studio that will not scroll.


My content is dynamic and the height of the view should vary dependent upon the data that is loaded from a database. I have searched and I am unable to find a way to set this programatically/dynamically in Xamarin.


I have seen some suggestions that I should put this in a scroll view but I'm unaware how to place controls in a ScrollView.


Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So you need to drag in a UIScrollview control into your View Controller. Connect this Scroll View with an outlet.

Now in order for the scroll view to scroll -> it needs to know the height of the content it is going to be holding. There are two ways of defining this:

If you are using **Auto Layout**:

1. Pin all of the Scroll View edges to the root view.
2. Make sure the Scroll View only has one descendant view.
3. Make everything else the subviews of the   descendant view.
4. Pin the descendant view edges to the Scroll View.
5. Set an equal width constraint between the descendant view and root view (scrollview's superview).
6. Pin the lowest subview in the descendant view to the bottom edge of
   the descendant view.

layout structure

```
[Root View]
  [ScrollView]
    [Descendant View]
      [UILabel]
      [UITextField]
      [UIButton]
      ...
```

This will set the ScrollView's Content Size dynamically.

If you are not using **Auto Layout**:

You  will need to determine what the height of the content is going to be and then set `ScrollView.ContentSize = height of the content`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer set my on the right lines. I programatically created a Scroll View inside of my UIViewController at load time and dynamically created my UI controls inside of this, each time I did so I created a new instance of Size and assigned it to the Scroll View's ContentSize property. This both enabled scrolling and serves to increase the size as new elements are added by the user.

Comment: This is probably the only solution I have seen so far that actually works well from setting up in code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to create a UITableView with UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate. Then for each type of control you would implement a UITableViewCell. Here is one example of generic table view that lets you override the height and cell getter which are the most important parts of the dynamic table view. The source is geared for Xamarin Forms but will work with native UITableView just fine.

https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Xamarin.Forms.Labs.iOS/Controls/DynamicListView/DynamicListViewRenderer.cs